# Are there free/paid DISTRIBUTED solvers for a large system pf linear equations?

Tags: optimization, distributed-systems, linear-algebra

I've been doings some research into distributed solutions for a large system of linear equations (reading papers such as Wang et al.'s "Solving a system of linear equations: From centralized to distributed algorithms"). Before implementing a solution myself I wanted to see if there are already any free or paid implementations but haven't had any luck. Do any of you have exposure to such a solution?

Comment: What do you call large ? When dealing with large systems, their structure matters a lot. Sparse or dense ?

Comment: By large I mean large enough to require a distributed solution. I would be interested in learning about any free or paid implementations (regardless of their limitations on matrix structure).

Comment: Maybe [Scalding](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Matrix-API-Reference/2899c4e5abab3ac2dfa541ed1b62c04b199160f8)? Or [Mahout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Mahout)?

Comment: Thanks @DirkT, I'll check them out!